# Updating Javascript Values from Swift

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift

I used some graph library and load the web pages into the `UIWebview` in my `Swift` project.

Is it possible to update the HTML file graph Y axis value from Swift `UIViewController`.

If it's possible, please suggest me some example.

More info please find the code and snap below.

**Startup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            // initial values of dataPoints
            var dps = [
                       {label: "Management Wing", y: 125}   ,
                       {label: "Production Lab", y: 332},
                       {label: "Cafeteria", y: 55},
                       {label: "Library", y: 46},
                       {label: "Recreation Centre", y: 32}
                       ];

                       alert(dps.y);

                       var totalEmployees = "Total people on campus: 590";

                       var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
                                                      theme: "theme2",
                                                      title:{
                                                      text: "People On Campus"
                                                      },
                                                      axisY: {
                                                      title: "Number of People"
                                                      },
                                                      legend:{
                                                      verticalAlign: "top",
                                                      horizontalAlign: "centre",
                                                      fontSize: 18

                                                      },
                                                      data : [{
                                                              type: "column",
                                                              showInLegend: true,
                                                              legendMarkerType: "none",             
                                                              legendText: totalEmployees,
                                                              indexLabel: "{y}",
                                                              dataPoints: dps
                                                              }]
                                                      });

                                                      // renders initial chart
                                                      chart.render();

                                                      var sum = 590;     //initial sum 

                                                      var updateInterval = 1000;  // milliseconds

                                                      var updateChart = function () {
                                                          // Selecting a random dataPoint
                                                          var dataPointIndex = Math.round(Math.random()*4);     

                                                          // generating random value
                                                          var deltaY = Math.round(2 + Math.random() *(-2-2));   

                                                          // adding random value to random dataPoint
                                                          dps[dataPointIndex].y = (dps[dataPointIndex].y + deltaY) > 0 ? dps[dataPointIndex].y + deltaY : 0 ;

                                                          // updating legend text. 
                                                          sum = sum + deltaY;
                                                          totalEmployees = "total people on campus: " + sum;            
                                                          chart.options.data[0].legendText = totalEmployees;    

                                                          chart.render();

                                                      };
                                                      // update chart after specified interval
                                                      setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval);

        }   
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Users/wipro/Shiv_Suthan_M_Drive/Suthan_Drive/Apple_Dev/Projects/Swift/SwiftScript/SwiftScript/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height:300px; width:100%;">
    </div>
</body>
```

**Viewcontroller.Swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let localfilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("startup", withExtension: "html")
    let myRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: localfilePath!);
    modelWebView.loadRequest(myRequest);

    /*
    let url = NSURL (string: "https://www.sourcefreeze.com");
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    modelWebView.loadRequest(requestObj);
    */


}
```

[image: Screen Shot]

So thing is I want to update the javascript datapoints (Y axis) from Swift .

Comment: Look at the documentation for the web view.

Comment: You have html as a string?

Comment: @Nirav I'm using below code to retrive the HTML string its working fine      do {
            let myHTMLString = try String(contentsOfURL: localfilePath!)
            print("HTML : \(myHTMLString)")
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        } But How can i change the datapoints and revert to JS ?

Comment: Have you try my answer? Fill free to ask question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your html file like below

```
var dps = [
    {label: "Management Wing", y: %ld},
    {label: "Production Lab", y: %ld},
    {label: "Cafeteria", y: %ld},
    {label: "Library", y: %ld},
    {label: "Recreation Centre", y: %ld}
];
```

Now change your code like this

```
let localfilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("demo", withExtension: "html")
do {
    var myHTMLString = try NSString(contentsOfURL: localfilePath!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    myHTMLString = NSString(format: myHTMLString, 123, 25, 100, 46, 85) // Add 5 number that you want to change
    webView.loadHTMLString(myHTMLString as String, baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("", withExtension: "")) //Add your js file here
}
catch let error as NSError
{
    print("Error: \(error.description)")
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: While i tried above I can't find the Graph in the webview, I guess the values not updated to JS ?? :( Anything else do i need to setup else the only two methods of yurs ??

Comment: have you put %ld instead of number in html?

Comment: I have edited my answer check that. You need to add the java script file in your project and give that file in the NSBundle in loadHTMLString

Comment: I'm not handling any separate JS file, I'm using HTML inside of JS function alone.. @Nirav Pls find the coding part of mine above.

Comment: I am talking about this `canvasjs.min.js` file

Comment: The code was working fine. But the values got changed continuously. I don't know the exact reason. Like If i provide 5 values 123, 25, 100, 46, 85 initially its loaded with this value but after that its got increasing and showing different values in the graph don't know why ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114714/discussion-between-nirav-doctorwala-and-shiv-suthan-m).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass parameter using jscript and update value on UIWebview.

Here is a useful link. Try this and apply your suitable logic. It's work form me. (This link is for objective c but it's work in swift also apply you suitable logic)

[JavascriptCore: pass javascript function as parameter in JSExport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607140/javascriptcore-pass-javascript-function-as-parameter-in-jsexport)

[Pass variables from Objective-C to javascript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100803/pass-variables-from-objective-c-to-javascript-function)

[How to invoke Objective C method from Javascript and send back data to Javascript in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826792/how-to-invoke-objective-c-method-from-javascript-and-send-back-data-to-javascrip)